# Using AdMob in many activities?

Tags: java, android, admob, adsense

So i have many activities , 
how can i use AdMob in every activity without loading it in every activity ?

Also why does my AdMob ad unit takes like 5 seconds to load ? can i make it load faster ?
I tried using AdMob in every activity , but 5 seconds to load in each time isn't good ..

I use an xml ad unit like this :

```
  <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         ads:adUnitId="MY_AD_UNIT_ID"
                         ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
```

Thanks so much ..,

Comment: what do you mean here : use AdMob **in every activity** *without* loading it **in every activity**

Comment: I suggest using a single activity with the AdView in the layout, and manage all your UI flow with fragments. Because it sounds like you have a lot of activities that users will navigate, so it makes it much less likely for ads to get clicked because of that load time.